# HoloLens external rendering

Tags: rendering, gpu, cpu, augmented-reality, hololens

Does soneone of you have a good solution for external rendering for Microsoft HoloLens Apps? Specified: Is it possible to let my laptop render an amount of 3D objects that is too much for the HoloLens GPU and then display them with the HoloLens by wifi including the spatial mapping and interaction?

Comment: Take a look at Unity Remoting, although I think it's designed for quick testing rather than production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to render remotely both directly from the unity editor and from a built application.

While neither achieves your goal of a "good solution" they both allow very intensive applications to at least run at all.

This walks you through how to add it to an app you're building.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/add-holographic-remoting

This is for running directly from the editor:
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/05/30/create-enhanced-3d-visuals-with-holographic-emulation-in-uwp/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are right that I will never get a proper solution by remote rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible since, you can't really access the OS or the processor at all on the HoloLens. Even if you do manage to send the data to a 3rd party to process, the data will still need to be run back through the HoloLens which is really just the same as before.

You may find a way to perhaps hook up a VR backpack to it but even then, I highly doubt it would be possible.

If you are having trouble rendering 3D objects, then you should reduce the number of triangles, get a lower resolution shader on it, or reduce the size of the object. The biggest factor in processing 3D objects on the HoloLens is how much space is being drawn on the lens. If your object takes up 25% of the view instead of 100% it will be easier to process on the HoloLens.

Also if you can't avoid a lot of objects in the scene maybe check out LOD, which reduces the resolution of objects based off of distance to it and vice versa.